# Color and shape aesthetics in facet_grid when margins presented

Tags: r, ggplot2, margins, facet-grid, aesthetics

Consider the following data:

```
n <- 1000  
data <- data.frame(id = 1:n,
                 a = sample(c("a1", "a2"), n, replace = T),
                 b = sample(c("b1", "b2", "b3"), n, replace = T),
                 x = rnorm(n),
                 y = rnorm(n))
```

I am creating a scatter plot in a grid for each combination of **a** and **b** with margins.

```
library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = b, shape = a)) +
  facet_grid(a ~ b, margins = T)
```

This creates an extra level for both factors called **(all)**, which for me is pointless.

I would like to obtain the effect where points are distinguished by color and shape even on marginal plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to create a variable to do the coloring and faceting independently:

```
n <- 1000  
data <- data.frame(id = 1:n,
                   a = sample(c("a1", "a2"), n, replace = T),
                   b = sample(c("b1", "b2", "b3"), n, replace = T),
                   x = rnorm(n),
                   y = rnorm(n)) %>%
  mutate(a_ = factor(a),
         b_ = factor(b))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = b, shape = a)) +
  facet_grid(a_ ~ b_, margins = T)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hoped I won't have to add extra variables for this, but I guess this is the only way to do this right now.